# matplotlib showing dates wrong

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

As a example to reproduce:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [datetime.today() + timedelta(days=i) for i in range(20)]
plt.plot(x, range(len(x)))
plt.show()
```

and I'm getting this plot. What is happening and how to fix it? matplotlib version 3.3.0 and python version 3.7.2

[image: wrong matplotlib dates]

Comment: have you tried setting the timezone? datetime.timezone.utc

Comment: Would a wrong time zone setting really cause the *dates* to be off by almost two thousand years?

Comment: No repro here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my computer I have not this problem when running the code, so try setting the time manually:

```
d = datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 23)
```

Also, check your system time to see if there is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using matplotlib version 3.3.0. Rolling back to version 3.2.0 fixed the problem for me.